# Асинхронный запуск PowerShell скрипта на C# .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, shell, powershell, асинхронность

Есть метод, который асинхронно читает из потока выполнения PowerShell скрипта (обязательным условием является асинхронное чтение, так как выполняемый скрипт может быть долгим, а главный поток приложения не должен ждать выполнения этого скрипта):

```
public PowerShell _powerShell;
public StringBuilder _outputText;
public StringBuilder _outputError;

public void Execute()
{
    string textOutput = string.Empty;
    string errorOutput = string.Empty;

    _powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
    _powerShell.AddScript("Get-Process | Out-String");
    PSDataCollection<PSObject> outCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    outCollection.DataAdded += outCollection_DataAdded;
    _powerShell.InvocationStateChanged += PShell_InvocationStateChanged;

    IAsyncResult _result = _powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outCollection);

    if (_powerShell.InvocationStateInfo.State == PSInvocationState.Error)
        errorOutput += _outputError.ToString();

    textOutput += _outputText.ToString();
}

private void outCollection_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    PSDataCollection<PSObject> psObjects = (PSDataCollection<PSObject>)sender;
    Collection<PSObject> results = psObjects.ReadAll();
    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        _outputText.AppendLine(result.ToString());
    }
}

private void PShell_InvocationStateChanged(object sender, PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.InvocationStateInfo.State == PSInvocationState.Failed)
        _outputError.AppendLine(_powerShell.Streams.Error.ToString());
}
```

Однако, значения *textOutput* и *errorOutput* на выходе всегда пустые(( Что делаю не так?
**P.S.:** как получить id запущенного процесса с выполняющимся скриптом (числовой id, который виден в Task Manager)?

**Полезные ссылки:**
[Get Powershell command's output when invoked through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398023/get-powershell-commands-output-when-invoked-through-code)
[Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)
[about_Execution_Policies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847748.aspx)

Comment: Не используйте foreach. Вы уже используете событие DataAdded - чем оно вам не нравится?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, отредактировал вопрос. В таком случае, как без цикла получать элемент коллекции для этого: **_outText.AppendLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());**?

Comment: Мой ответ не изменился. Используйте событие.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, чтобы ваш ответ был полным.

Comment: Пример кода вы можете увидеть в своем вопросе. Там надо просто 3 строчки удалить и одну переставить в другое место.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, пробовал то, что вы советуете, мой код эволюционировал в то, что вы видите выше. Однако, это не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш случай - классическая ситуация вида "делаю то, не знаю что". Рассмотрим вот эту строчку:

```
_powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outCollection);
```

Почему вы выбрали метод `BeginInvoke` вместо `Invoke`? Да потому что вам не надо ждать завершения работы скрипта, вам надо запустить его в фоне!

Но почему тогда вы пишите `textOutput += _outputText.ToString();` строчкой ниже *как будто скрипт уже отработал*? Ведь вы сами только что приняли решения не ждать окончания его работы!

Что можно сделать? Можно воспользоваться событиями. Вы же не просто так выбрали сложный способ получения данных по частям - вам надо их вот так по частям и обрабатывать. Не накапливать в `_outputText`, а сразу делать с ними что там хотели с ними сделать.

Если же я ошибся и вам именно что надо получить их однократно - то выкиньте что вы написали и воспользуйтесь [другой формой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182439(v=vs.85).aspx) метода `BeginInvoke`:

```
public void Execute()
{
    _powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
    _powerShell.AddScript("Get-Process | Out-String");
    _powerShell.InvocationStateChanged += PShell_InvocationStateChanged;
    _powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject>(null, new PSInvocationSettings(), Execute_Complete, null);
}

void Execute_Complete(IAsyncResult ar, object unused)
{
    var outCollection = _powerShell.EndInvoke(ar);

    // и здесь делайте с outCollection что хотите
}
```